# Bootstrap visibility classes working but content not removed from markup

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, class, visibility

I am using bootstrap visibility classes as follows on my webpage:

```
<div class="hidden-sm">
   <div id="lrg-div-A"></div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-lrg">
   <div id="lrg-div-B"></div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-md">
   <div id="lrg-div-C"></div>
</div>
```

The visibility classes work and are hidden in the viewport where required. But, when I look at the markup in the browser's developer tools, I still see the markup for the hidden divs. For example, on large screens, "lrg-div-B" is not seen in the viewport, but the markup is still seen in the HTML tab. Is there anyway to remove it from the markup as well, similar to what 'dispaly: none' does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: none` doesn't remove it from the markup, but it does remove it from the document flow so that it doesn't take up space. You can remove a node with javascript using `remove()` or `removeChild()` but mind you can't get it back again (unless you store it and re-append it later).

```js
console.log('Hidden node: ', document.querySelector('.hidden-sm'));
//Hidden node:  <div class="hidden-sm">…</div>

console.log('Before remove(): ', document.getElementById('lrg-div-B'));
// Before remove():  <div id="lrg-div-B">large B</div>

document.getElementById('lrg-div-B').remove();
console.log('Removed node: ', document.getElementById('lrg-div-B')); 
// Removed node:  null
```

```css
.hidden-sm {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden-sm"> <!-- hidden but still in markup -->
   <div id="lrg-div-A">large A</div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-lrg">
   <div id="lrg-div-B">large B</div> <!-- removed from markup -->
</div>
<div class="hidden-md">
   <div id="lrg-div-C">large C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, if I am understanding right, unlike 'display:none', remove() will remove it from the markup, not just the document?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by document and markup, `remove()` will delete the node it is called on from the DOM tree until the page is refreshed. The node will no longer be able to be referenced or fetched from the DOM.

Comment: I was referencing the exact terms you used in your answer 'doesn't remove it from the markup, but it does remove it from the document....'

Answer (score 0):

It is not supposed to remove the elements from markup. CSS handles how DOM looks not its structure. You need to use a bit of Javascript if you actually want to remove the DOM elements.